# How to install LuaSQL for Lua(La)TeX on Windows with MikTeX

Tags: luatex, windows, lua, database

I would really like to be able to pull data directly from ODBC databases into **LuaLaTeX** and it seems as if the **LuaSQL** package is the way to go. But for the life of me, after a couple of days of trying, I cannot get it to install, even for a standalone Lua installation.

I have tried installing via **luarocks** - which required me to install Visual Studio 2015 and the Windows 10 SDK for headers etc. - but I can't get it to compile. Lots of messing about trying to make sure there weren't any spaces in folder names, for example, but to no avail.

I have also tried using the Windows binaries available from [luaforge.net](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luasql/luasql/LuaSQL2.0.1) despite their 2005 date, but can't get lua to load them ("The specified module could not be found").

Is anyone using Lua(La)TeX with LuaSQL successfully? If so, would you mind sharing how you did it?!

Comment: I am coming to the conclusion that my best option is a bespoke build of luatex.exe with LuaSQL baked in - I've asked [this  question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/bake-luasql-into-luatex-binary-on-windows) on how to do this.

Comment: I don't think so, compiling the modules on Windows is the hard task, it is quite easy to place it to a correct directory once it is built.

Comment: On Debian, and probably Debian-derived distributions, as of this writing, this issue does not exist, because LuaSQL is a Debian package. I realise this doesn't answer your question, but consider working on a different operating system.